# Canticle bark, or, unseen uses

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I gathered the bark with no problem, but am confused about its purpose.other than causing the ancestor moths to swarm you(?) does the stuff serve any other function?

Answer (score 2):

It's jut a quest item, so no. Ancestor moth wing is an alchemical ingredient, so it remains useful, but unfortunately [ancestor moths attracted by canticle bark aren't harvestable](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ancestor_Moth_Wing), so it's not even useful for that purpose. You can drop the draw knife and canticle bark after completion of the quest.

Comment: Thanks for the info..tried to gather the ancestor moths after that leg of the quest..they disappeared whenever I got to them..probably just a glitch. Will go back later and try again

Comment: Looks like I'm wrong about the canticle bark being useful for harvesting ancestor moths. I'll edit my answer to reflect that.